# Help with this issue

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, opengl

Here is my issue. I'm rendering axis alligned cubes that are all the same size. I created an algorithm that rendered around the player like this:

```
******
******
***p**
******
******
```

While this does work, the player does not see this whole radius.
I know the player's rotation angle on the Y, so I was hoping to modify my algorithm based on this so that it would only render about, what the player can see more or less.

```
SetPlayerPosition();
float yrotrad;
yrotrad = (Camera.roty / 180 * 3.141592654f);




PlayerPosition.x += 70 * float(sin(yrotrad));
PlayerPosition.y -= 20;
PlayerPosition.z += 70 * -(float(cos(yrotrad)));

collids.clear();
for(int i = 0; i < 135; ++i)
{
 for(int j = 0; j < 50; ++j)
 {
  for(int k = 0; k < 135; ++k)
  {
   if(!CubeIsEmpty(PlayerPosition.x + i, PlayerPosition.y + j, PlayerPosition.z + k))
   {
    collids.push_back(GetCube(PlayerPosition.x + i, PlayerPosition.y + j, PlayerPosition.z + k));
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Basically, my original algorithm would just subtract 70 from the players location, and render the square that is 70 in size. So I tried to multiply these by the sin and cos os the Y rotation but it did not work. I'm sure this is possible, I just think i'm missing something. How could I achieve my goal of only rendering ~what the player sees.

Thanks

Just as a note, I tried frustrum culling and this got too slow, I'd rather this which works no matter how many cubes I have

instead of rendering the above id like it to only, ex if the player is facing ->

```
...... ****
...... ****
......P****
...... ****
```

Comment: Can you provide a graphical example of what you think the player *should* see, so we can better understand what you are looking for?

Comment: I'm making a 3d fps when u can rotate the camera around the player on the Y

Comment: Basically if the angle is 0, it should render playerpos  +- say 10 on the X and maybe playerpos + [0,80] on the Z

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at your code again, maybe this is your problem:

```
PlayerPosition.x += 70.0f * float(sin(yrotrad));
PlayerPosition.y -= 20;
PlayerPosition.z += 70.0f * -(float(cos(yrotrad)));
```

and what types are the coordinates?

Comment: the coordinates are in Cubes, not camera coords, that might be the issue, a cube is 3.5 units in size

Comment: @Milo: So ints, which will be fine, but notice that I changed the 70 to 70.0f, which will force the multiplication to happen as a float, and therefore not throw away the sin and cos, which will be < 1

Comment: still though its not doing what i intended, it renders only what the player sees at angle 0 but if I for example rotate the player 180 degrees, I see nothing

Comment: @Milo: put a break point in and check the value of Camera.roty. PS, if you put @DominicMcDonnell I'll get informed of your comment

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand your code ( 70 ? CubeIsEmpty ?) but if Cube-frustum is too slow, you could try sphere-frustum.

http://www.chadvernon.com/blog/resources/directx9/frustum-culling/